# OpenCV Transparent API UMat is missing

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, javacv

I tried to use `OpenCV` `Transparent API` `UMat` class for hardware acceleration in my desktop java application but I couldn't find the `UMat` class implementation. I'm using `OpenCV version 4.1`, where `T-API` java bindings are said to be available up from `version 3.0` as said [here](https://opencv.org/opencv-3-0/):

> T-API (transparent API) has been introduced, this is transparent GPU
>   acceleration layer using OpenCL. It does not add any compile-time or
>   runtime dependency of OpenCL. When OpenCL is available, it’s detected
>   and used, but it can be disabled at compile time or at runtime. It
>   covers ~100 OpenCV functions. This work has been done by contract and
>   with generous support from AMD and Intel companies.

- Is `T-API` deprecated? If yes, what replaces it?
- And by the way what is the `OpenCV Graph API` [G-API](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d0/d1e/gapi.html)? Is it a replacement for the `T-API`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this question down.

> **Is T-API deprecated? If yes, what replaces it?**

No, T-API is not effectively deprecated. You can see it [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.1.2/modules/core/src/umatrix.cpp), that the T-API is still alive under the OpenCV 4.1.2 version tag. **Your main issue is that there is no actual Java wrapper for the T-API**, as we can see [at this answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/105033/use-gpu-on-java-opencv/) and we can't see a *UMat* implementation under the [OpenCV Java Docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/package-summary.html).

> **And by the way what is the OpenCV Graph API G-API? Is it a replacement for the T-API?**

Again, looking at [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.2/d6/dc9/gapi_purposes.html), we read:

> OpenCV 3.0 introduced Transparent API (or T-API) which allowed to offload OpenCV function calls transparently to OpenCL devices and save on Host/Device data transfers with cv::UMat – and it was a great step forward. However, T-API is a dynamic API – user code still remains unconstrained and OpenCL kernels are enqueued in arbitrary order, thus eliminating further pipeline-level optimization potential. G-API brings implicit graph model to OpenCV 4.0. Graph model captures all operations and its data dependencies in a pipeline and so provides G-API framework with extra information to do pipeline-level optimizations.

As it is documented, the G-API doesn't seems to be a "replacement", but more like and improvement of the OpenCV hardware accelerating initiatives. Instead of having just some optimized operations over unorganized kernels, G-API brings a pipe-line/graph oriented paradigm to the newer versions of OpenCV.